# Count other documents in the same table matching the condition

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I've got this query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM default t USE KEYS default.id
            WHERE t.p_id=default.id
    ) as children_count
FROM default
WHERE 1
```

I expect this:

```
[
  {
    "children_count": 5,
    "id": "1"
  },
  ...
]
```

But i got this:

```
[
  {
    "children_count": [
      {
        "$1": 0
      }
    ],
    "id": "1"
  },
  ...
]
```

What am I doing wrong? I've googled this, but I can't find any clear explaination of count subqueries in N1QL, so any links to documentation will be highly appreciated.

**UPD:**

I've updated my code according to @prettyvoid answer. I've also created minimal example bucket to demonstrate the problem.

```
SELECT
    id,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as count
            FROM test t USE KEYS "p.id"
            WHERE t.p_id=p.id
    )[0].count as children_count
FROM test p
WHERE 1
```

[image: Sorry, I don't know how to export buckets from CB]

The result is following:

```
[
  {
    "children_count": 0,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "children_count": 0,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "children_count": 0,
    "id": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of what your documents look like? There may be better ways to write the query depending on the structure of the documents.

Comment: @EbenH generally, each document has its `id` and `p_id` fields, where `p_id` is parent id and matches `id` field of some another document (but may be not set). `id` is internal and may be not equal to document key, but I can force them to be equal if thats necessary. Other fields are just some irrelevant json, but in my real query I'm querrying them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `select` statement will yield you an array with objects inside, that's normal. If you want to get your expected result then scope-in to the count object inside the array [0]

**edit**: Following query will do what you want, I'm unsure if there is a better way though

```
SELECT
    id,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count
        FROM default t USE KEYS (SELECT RAW meta().id from default)
        WHERE t.p_id=p.id
    )[0].count as children_count
FROM default p
```

Comment: But still I'm getting 0 instead of expected count. I've even tried to replace where clause in subquery with `where 1`, but this way I'm always getting 1, which is way smaller than the amount of documents in `default` bucket.

Comment: Well I have no idea of your data. Are there two or more types of documents in your bucket? Update your post with samples of the documents involved. Upload to pastebin or whatever

Comment: Upvote for a good approach, however it fails to output elements with zero chldren_count, plus in my real case I want to output other fields except the id as well.

Comment: I don't understand... According to your examples, each document in your bucket have a p_id (parent id), so each parent will have a specific count of children (whether its 0 or >0). If that's not the case then you need to explain more and stop assuming that people here will magically know all the details :). As for the other fields you can add them to your `select` clause.

Comment: I've already provided an example. Your code assumes if there's a document with `id`, there always would be another document with `p_id` equal to this `id`. This assumption is wrong, and my example illustrates it. 2nd and 3rd documents won't be processed at all, but I expect them to be processed and show `children_count` equal to 0.

Comment: Ok I understand what you need now. At least I know why your original query with (USE KEYS) is not working, it's because USE KEYS function on the primary key of the documents, which is in your case (a,b,c,d).. so basically you're matching those primary keys against (1,2,3,4) which will never match.

Comment: @DenisSheremet Check latest

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that in Couchbase, the very fastest way to retrieve a document is via its document key. Using a GSI index is workable, but slower. And as with most other databases, it is best to avoid a full scan. You say you can make `id` the same as the document key, so I will assume that is the case, so that I can use `p_id` in the `on keys` clause.

Is it o.k. to only list documents with a non-zero number of children? In that case, you can write this as an aggregation query where you join each child to its parent, and group by the parent id (note my bucket is called `default`):

`select p.id, count(*) as children_count 
 from default c join default p on keys c.p_id 
 group by p.id;`

If you need to include documents with zero children, you need to `UNION` with a query that finds those documents as well. In this case we know that:

`select raw array_agg(distinct(p_id)) from default where p_id is not null`

will give us an array of parent IDs, so we can get the ids not in the list with:

`select id, 0 as children_count 
 from default p
 where not array_contains(
   (select raw array_agg(distinct(p_id)) from default where  p_id is not null)[0],id);`

So, if we `UNION` the two:

`(select p.id, count(*) as children_count 
 from default c join default p on keys c.p_id 
 group by p.id)
UNION 
(select id, 0 as children_count 
from default p
where not array_contains(
   (select raw array_agg(distinct(p_id)) from default where p_id is not null)[0],id));`

We get a list of all the ids and their children_count, zero or not. If you want more than just the id, add more fields or '*' to the select list for each query.